# KinectSensor.DepthStream.OpenNextFrame returns NULL

Tags: c#, wcf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to build a simple WCF service that returns the depth data from the Kinect sensor. Here's my code:

```
[DataContract]
public class DepthFrame
{
    [DataMember]
    public short[] depthData { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IKinectTools
{     
    [OperationContract]
    DepthFrame getDepthData(); 
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class KinectTools : IKinectTools
{ 
    public DepthFrame getDepthData()
    {            
        DepthFrame df = new DepthFrame();
        KinectSensor kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        kinect.DepthStream.Enable();
        kinect.Start();
        DepthImageFrame depthFrame = kinect.DepthStream.OpenNextFrame(5);
        df.depthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(df.depthData);
        return df;
    }            
}
```

but the code is not working. When I run the service, I get an error at the following line

```
df.depthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
```

because the depthFrame is null.
How come the depthFrame variable is null while I'm calling the OpenNextFrame method?

---

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the full exception trace please?

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   http://s12.postimg.org/eo2laxdbh/image.png

Comment: Hang on - something just occurred to me. When you say "a WCF service", do you mean "running in session 0 as part of IIS"? I'd be very surprised if the Kinect SDK was safe to call from a service context so if you're doing that you might need to think of a different approach. Many windows APIs are not supported when working in a service context.

Comment: @Stewart - I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "session 0", but what I'm doing is building a WCF project to handle the kinect data. And right now, I don't care about the hosting process such as IIS since I'm using the visual studio to host and test the service. I added a picture above. Thanks

Comment: Sorry - Session 0 is Windows jargon for "running in a service, such as IIS". The WCF test client probably isn't running as a service, so that probably isn't the issue - although I don't know very much about WCF at all. Having said that - if you're planning to run it as a service, you should probably check that works before getting too much further.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.depthimagestream.opennextframe.aspx says that the function will return null if the wait time elapses before a frame is available. Since you're specifying a wait time of 5ms this is quite likely to happen. Especially as you only just started the sensor so it may not have finished starting up yet (some of its startup is asynchronous). You need to either specify a longer timeout for the next frame, or handle the null case.

In my game, I poll for a new frame on every game frame specifying a timeout of zero. If the result is null I use the last frame. During game startup I wait for the first frame to become available so that I don't have to deal with the edge case where we haven't got the first frame yet. This is neat because it allows the game frame rate to be decoupled from the Kinect frame rate (which is ideally much lower).

Comment: I changed the wait time, and it is still not working:( I'm not sure what the best way is to handle the null case, and there is no last frame in my case! Thank you.

Comment: What did you increase the wait time to? As a debugging exercise you could try setting it to int.MaxValue so that in practise it can never elapse and see if you get a frame. As I said - in my Xbox 360 game what I do with this is to have a single call passing INFINITE for the timeout on startup. After that I always pass 0 for the timeout, and if it returns null I just reuse the value I got last time.

Comment: I tried different values, and it didn't work. I also tried to use a loop:  `do
                {
                    depthFrame = kinect.DepthStream.OpenNextFrame(20);
                } while (depthFrame == null); `    and I got another WCF error which is "Failed to invoke the service." @Stewart

Comment: I just tried using int.MaxValue, and I got this error "Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service." Maybe I need to figure out another way to build the WCF service that can get the Kinect data. I'm not sure if that even possible!  Thanks